# mkdir gives "No space left on device" message but sudo mkdir works

Tags: permissions, disk-usage, storage, mkdir, deleted-files

When I try to use `mkdir test` in /home/, I get `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: No space left on device`. I've deleted over 1Gb of files and restarted some processes that were using deleted files, but I can't restart processes `networkd-`, `systemd-l`, and `unattende`.

When I run `df -h /` now I get

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        49G   48G     0 100% /
```

and `mkdir test` still doesn't work but `sudo mkdir test` does, why is that? I also tried `sudo chmod 777 .` in said directory, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

(Some) file systems have a feature to reserve a percentage of space for root usage. This seems to be exactly what's happening here.

The things you deleted don't seem to suffice to lift the available space percentage over that threshold.

Assuming this is ext4, 'man tune2fs' would be the right tool to use to adjust the percentage. For other file systems, other tools.